# Display 2 clocks in the top panel

Tags: 14.04, gnome, time

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome Flashback (Compiz)

I'm currently working abroad - it would be useful to see my employers time in the top panel in addition to my local time.

I've already added the time zones to the clock, so can see them if I click the time. But it would be nice if I could see *both clocks next to each other*.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/

Comment: How do I display 2 times in different time zones along the top panel :) Well... an additional time, I already have the local time displayed by the clock applet.